# about ado.net for searching

Tags: .net

i want to search from database product name in ado.net.when user enter the full name of the product it gets results but i want that when user enter the first letter the text changed event invoke and get results according to first letter.e.g if user enter only 'e' it get all results according to the e and show it in datagridview

```
    private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hamad"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet dtt = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from product where pname = '" + textBox10.Text.ToString() + "'", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter();
        daa.SelectCommand = cmd;
        daa.Fill(dtt, "product");
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dtt;
        dataGridView2.DataMember = "product";
        dataGridView2.Visible = true;
    }
```

please help me.i think alot

Comment: And what is your problem in reference to the code above?

Comment: PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE pay attention to the first line of SWeko's answer; then go and revisit **ALL** of your existing data access code. You should **never** concatenate input.

Answer (score 2):

First, and valid even if the assumptions of my answer are incorrect, **never, ever** append a text the user supplied to an SQL statement. That is asking for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) problems

---

I would guess that you need all results that *begin* with the text the user entered in the text-box.

You are asking the the database for any entries that are *exactly* what the has entered in the database, so when the user looks for, let's say books, he will need to enter the compleat title of the book, or it will not be returned. That's not much of a search :)

To do that you need to use the [`like` sql operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), insead of using `=`. Try changing the line:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from product where pname = '" + textBox10.Text.ToString() + "'", conn);
```

with

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from product where pname like @pname+'%'", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValues("@pname", textBox10.Text);
```

This should (safely) return any products where the name starts with the string entered.

Answer (score 0):

1. The textChange Event invokes when user press tab, press enter or click on something outside textbox.
2. You have to use like in sql query if you want to search from a part of string.

Try this

```
  private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hamad"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    DataSet dtt = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from product where pname like @pname+'%'", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValues("@pname", textBox10.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter();
    daa.SelectCommand = cmd;
    daa.Fill(dtt, "product");
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dtt;
    dataGridView2.DataMember = "product";
    dataGridView2.Visible = true;
  }
```

This will display all records starting with the character you type.
**Note**; All this will be done if you press tab, press enter or click on something outside textbox.